# Is there a way to make a node of Linkedlist point to a node that isnt next in the list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am making a snakes and ladders game in C using a LinkedList, I have a square struct that represents squares on the board. I need to add snakes and ladder that when the player cursor lands on them the move the cursor forward or backward depending on if its a snake or a ladder. Is it possible to make a node in a linkedlist point to something other than the next node in the list

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//structure for a square of the board 
struct Square{  //structure that respresents squares on the board
    int number;         //its number on the board
   
    struct Square *next;            //pointer to the next node

};
typedef struct Square square;

//this function will create a square
square *create_Square(int num) {
    square *sq  = malloc(sizeof(square));   //allocate memory
    sq->number=num;
    sq->next= NULL;         //points to null because the new one is added to the end of the linkedlist
    return sq;
}

//function to insert a square onto the board
square *insertSquare(square *newSquare, square *head){
    newSquare->next = head;            //pointing the new squares next to the head
    return newSquare;                   //returning the pointer to the new square which will become the head
}

int main(){
     square *head = NULL;   //pointer to the first node of the list
     square *tempSquare;        //will be used as temporary structures for creating the ladders

     //randomising the board
    srand(time(0));
    int upper = 64;      //setting the limits of the randomisation  
    int lower = 32;    
    int boardSize = (rand() % (upper-lower+1)) + lower;
    int ladderOne = (rand() % (10-1+1)) + 1;
    int ladderTwo =(rand() % (10-1+1)) + 1;

     
//creating the board
    for (int i = 0; i <= boardSize; i++)
    {
            if(i==rand){
                
            }
             tempSquare = create_Square(i);           //using a temporary square to create new squares
             head = insertSquare(tempSquare,head);     //the head will equal the pointer of the newest square
             
        
    }

    printBoard(head);

}
```

Comment: ***Is there a way to make a node of Linkedlist point to a node that isnt next in the list*** Yes you can have it point to any node. However does that make sense? How do you traverse the list if some random node does not point to the next?

Comment: I traverse the nodes of the list one by one but when I hit a ladder it pushes me 10 squares forward(instead of 1) like the snakes and ladders game. This was my idea but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement this ladder

Comment: Can you keep the list as it is and write a function to advance the 10 squares?

Comment: Of course that would be the easiest implementation but the exercise was to make the ladder a pointer to another square and the ladder has to have a length between 1-10 so Im trying to figure this out to improve my knowledge of pointers

Comment: Maybe you need to add a second pointer other than next which would jump ahead or back.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The definition of `printBoard` is missing. Aside: most of the comments in the code are rather superfluous or incorrect (`create_Square` and `insertSquare` contradict each other with regards to the position of the new node in the list).

Comment: Your compiler should be squawking loudly about the line `if(i==rand){` because you are comparing an integer with a function pointer.  Maybe you intended to call `rand()` again.  The chances of `i` equalling the new return value are very small.  Avoid posting code that doesn't compile cleanly.

Comment: For better visualization I always recommend using pencil and paper to draw lists (and similar data-structures), using boxes for nodes and other variables and arrows for pointers and links. As you modify the list, erase and redraw the arrows. As long as the drawing makes sense all is probably well and fine. If the drawing stops making sense then you have a problem.

Comment: I also recommend using the drawing technique to visualize what is happening in your program while stepping through it in a *debugger*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm responding to the question in the header. I'm not familiar with the Snakes And Ladders game, so I skipped the rest.

The answer is "No" and "Yes".

It's "No" because "next" means next: The one that follows in a sequence.

It's "Yes" because, in a linked list, there is no requirement whatever `next` points to has to be physically near the `current` node.

In short, "next" is a based on a *logical* relationship, not necessarily a *physical* relationship.

Consider that when you allocate memory for a new node and link an existing node to it, the two nodes might be in memory locations that are adjacent, or dozens, hundreds, or thousands of bytes apart.

Suppose you are working on an application for the Office of the Registrar at a college. The people there want to be able to quickly list students in alphabetical order or by student ID order. The college Honor Society wants to see students listed in GPA order. Instead of sorting, you decide to maintain the list in all 3 orders requested.

You can use a triply-linked list, represented by the table below:

**Initial: No students in table**

headName = 0, headSID = 0, headGPA = 0

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**The first student is added:**

headName = 1, headSID = 1, headGPA = 1

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**The 2nd student is added:**

headName = 1, headSID = 1, headGPA = 1

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Wilson, George | 39572 | 3.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

George Wilson is after Mary Brown in all three orderings.

**The 3rd student is added:**

headName = 1, headSID = 1, headGPA = 3

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Wilson, George | 39572 | 3.00 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | Mitchell, Dennis | 87523 | 3.51 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

Dennis Mitchell is between Mary Brown and George Wilson in name order, last in SID order, and first in GPA order

**The 4th Student is added:**

headName = 1, headSID = 1, headGPA = 4

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Wilson, George | 39572 | 3.00 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | Mitchell, Dennis | 87523 | 3.51 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Wade, Margaret | 77920 | 4.00 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

**The 5th Student is added:**

headName = 5, headSID = 1, headGPA = 4

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Wilson, George | 39572 | 3.00 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | Mitchell, Dennis | 87523 | 3.51 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Wade, Margaret | 77920 | 4.00 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | Aarrons, Adam | 40001 | 3.60 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

**The 6th Student is added:**

headName = 5, headSID = 1, headGPA = 4

| R | Name | SID | GPA | nNam | nSID | nGPA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown, Mary | 24972 | 3.24 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Wilson, George | 39572 | 3.00 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | Mitchell, Dennis | 87523 | 3.51 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Wade, Margaret | 77920 | 4.00 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | Aarrons, Adam | 40001 | 3.60 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 6 | Feeder, Bottom | 64211 | 1.87 | 3 | 4 | 0 |

When a student is added, append the student data to the end of the table, or in your case, the list. For each linkage, follow the `next` pointers until you find the two old students the new student goes between. Set the `next` pointer for the new student to point to whatever the `next` pointer in the previous old student was pointing to, and set the `next` pointer in the "previous" old student to point to the new student.

In doing so, you make adjustments if the new student will be first or last in a chain.

**Notes:**

To fit the width allotted,  I shortened "nextName", "nextSID", and "nextGPA"  to "nNam", "nSID", "nGPA", respectively.

"Pointers" are to row numbers ("R") in the table. A value of zero means there is no `next` or `header` to point to; i.e., the last in the chain.

Name and Student ID are in ascending order. GPA is descending.

If it helps, print this out and draw arrows corresponding to the `head` and `next` pointers.